# Algorithm to find the furthest point on 2D from other points

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 2D map with points. I need to find a place where I can put a new point and it will be the furthest point from the closest neighbors.

Example, I have a map:

```
start.x = 0
start.y = 0
end.x = 100
end.y = 100

and array of points List<Point> = {(10,10), (50, 50), (90, 90)}

The result is (0, 100).
```

So far I found only possible solution using voronoi diagramms:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: What's with the language tag spam? You can't honestly be using three programming languages. Also, this question is too broad: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What does the boundary of your map look like?

Comment: The new position is a Voronoi center, so you can hardly avoid Voronoi diagrams. If you need to do that repeatedly, Fortune's algorithm may not be the best (it isn't incremental). There are many implementations of Voronoi diagrams on the web, you shouldn't be scared of using one of them, no need to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: @Oleksii Shyshkov What do you mean by `furthest point from the closest neighbors` ?

Comment: For example you want to find a place on the beach but you would like to be as far as possible from the nearest neighbors.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet? I'm having the same underlying problem and am still looking for a solution.